# Hangfire aspnetcore2 default authentication challenge not working

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, openid-connect, hangfire

Using **hangfire** version: 1.6.17
I have successfully setup hangifire on **aspnetcore 2.0**
I added authorization by using:

```cs
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/jobs", new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new[] { new HangfireAuthorizationFilter() }
});
```

and

```cs
public class HangfireAuthorizationFilter :IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    private const string PERMISSION = "read:jobs";
    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();
        // allow only users with correct permission
        if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var permissions = httpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals(CustomClaims.Permissions))?.Value?.Split(' ');
            return permissions?.Contains(PERMISSION) ?? false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The only problem i cannot resolve is that a blank screen with 401 is returned to the user instead of the default challenge /account/login.

If you access my controllers with the [Authorize] attribute, they are automatically redirected to /account/login, so the loginpath is working.

Even if i specify it specifically, the user is not redirected while accessing Hangfire unauthorised:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
 .AddCookie(options =>
 {
     options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/";
 })
```

Somebody an idea or should i mark it as a bug at Hangfire github.

Comment: Hello, did you find a fix for this?

Comment: No, but i implemented a work around by redirecting to the login page and specifying the redirecturl myself in the querystring. Not a decent work around but no other option as i don't get any feedback about it.

Answer (score 0):

First you should add HangFireAuthorizationFilter

```
    public sealed class HangFireAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public HangFireAuthorizationFilter(IAuthorizationService authorizationService,
    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _authorizationService = authorizationService;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
    {
        var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();
        return httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Then use the below in the startup:

```
    var hangFireAuth = new DashboardOptions
        {
            Authorization = new[]
            {
            new HangFireAuthorizationFilter(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IAuthorizationService>(),
            app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>())
            },
            AppPath = "/login"
        };
        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", options: hangFireAuth);
```

You can refer to the following https://medium.com/ricos-note/hangfire-dashboard-of-authorization-b41d7135b044 for more details